# How can we use dependency functionality that is present in jasmine

Tags: jasmine, testng, karma-runner, jasmine-node

In jasmine suite , if we have 10 specs , how can we arrange dependeny specs such that if any dependency specs are failed the jasmine should not execute other specs which has to be executed.

In testNG library which is used for java unit testing where  we are using dependency groups or methods  attribute on an @test annotation